# Using Case Statement in Where Clause ___ Using date ranges with BETWEEN

Tags: sql, oracle, date, case, where-clause

I am trying to filter a date to a specific range depending on whether or not we have passed the first weekday of the current month.

Oracle seems to not like that I am using `BETWEEN`.

```
WHEN   
TO_DATE(myDate,'YYYYMMDD')=CASE WHEN TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1) - TO_DATE(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1))+6)>0 
THEN  
TO_DATE(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1))+1, 'YYYYMMDD') --AND to_date(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1, 'YYYYMMDD')
Else   
TO_DATE(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -2))+1, 'YYYYMMDD') --AND to_date(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1, 'YYYYMMDD')
END
```

Please let me know how to correct this.

Comment: `sysdate`returns a `DATE` value, please do not use `TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1)`

Comment: And dates should be stored as dates. Is `myDate` a string you must convert into a date? Hopefully not. `TO_DATE(myDate,'YYYYMMDD')` should just be `myDate` or if you want to remove a time part: `TRUNC(myDate)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want dates that are equal to or after the first monday of the current month, you can do:

```
to_date(my_date, 'YYYYMMDD') >= next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - 1, 'MONDAY')
```

`trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - 1` gives you the last day of the previous month. Then `next_day(..., 'MONDAY')` gives you the following Monday.

You can change the day name according to what your definition of a *week day* is. Also, it is worth noting that the day name (the second argument to `next_day()` must be provided in the language of your session.